# Creating basic authentfcation configuration

Tags: qgis-3, authentication

I am trying to configure the master password on several machines. However, I have two machines that persistently give me this error. I tried uninstalling QGIS and that does not seem to solve the problem.

All machines are running the same version of QGIS 3.6 When I connect to the database for the first time and try to set the basic configuration it gives me the option to new master authentification password, I enter my credentials and the OK option remains inactive. Perhaps I need to configure something?

See screenshots below. The other machines do allows me to edit the configuration and work fine. I tried settings, options, authentification, utilities and still, it does not allow me to add a new configuration.

[image: example]

---

When doing this configuration, I always enter my Postgres superuser credentials. This does not work at first. When you give it a different user name and password. The password authentification manager allows you to create a new authentification, you can then enter your DB credentials, this way you won't be asked to enter the password when opening the QGIS project stored in postgreSQL.